# System.Io is not working properly

Tags: c#

I want to copy some text on textbox2 to a txt file.I want to create a `kk.txt` file after clicking the button and need to store textbox2 text to that `kk file`.

Here is the code i tried but it only create kk.txt file and not storing textbox2 data.

```
  private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //textBox4.Text +=Clipboard.GetText()+Environment.NewLine;
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox2.Text);

        System.IO.File.Create(@"C:/Ebaycodes/kk.txt");

        string path = @"C:/Ebaycodes/kk.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.Write(textBox2.Text);
                sw.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

could somebody help me to fix this error.

Comment: Change `!File.Exists(path)` to `File.Exists(path)`.You also don't need to create the file with File.Create, `File.CreateText` will do that when you write to it.

Comment: You can also just do File.WriteAllText(path, textBox2.text);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `if` statement, it only runs if the file **doesn't** exist. You created it, so it does exist, and the `if` doesn't run. You can change your entire routine to this:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(textBox2.Text);
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Ebaycodes\kk.txt", textbox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: We came to the same solution.. I didn't copy, you were first, I will delete my answer!